# Animation of two videos in Blender

Tags: objects

I am attempting to run one video over the top of another.  In the base video, I have a guy running down a street.  This video is on a plane.  I have a second video that I created with some pain to render a cheetah running with an alpha layer using WebM codec. I have inserted this video on a smaller plane and constrained the plane to the street of the first video using keyframes so that it appears that the cheetah is chasing the guy.  I am unable to get rid of the black background on the cheetah video. Any help would be grateful.  Running Blender 2.91
[image: Two videos on planes in Blender with one having an alpha layer]

Comment: https://youtu.be/wBZsD2obR5o?t=140

Answer (score 0):

Check the alpha blend method on the cheetah clip material settings. I recommend “hashed.” If that is correct, check that in the material the alpha of the image is connected to the shader’s alpha somehow (using a mix shader node with the alpha connected to the factor, and a transparent shader node on one input, works good).